# javax.mail: Get nested attachments in EML attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, eml

I have an existing code that downloads and processes some emails correctly.

The email to process must have one or more xml as attachment, now I'm **migrating** this process from the current standard mail account **to a certified system that wrap that mail into a new email**.

So, instead of a flat email with one xml attachment, I have to parse an email with an XML (the certified) and an EML (the message that I should process).

In short, my code is like the following:

```
private void processMessage(final Message message) {
    try {
        final String contentType = message.getContentType();
        if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
            final Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

            for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
                final MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);

                /**************************************************************
                 * HERE I CAN'T GET THE EML (and its attachments) FROM 'part' *
                 **************************************************************/

                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                    processAttachment(part);
                }
            }
        }
    } [...cutted...]
}

private void processAttachment(final MimeBodyPart part) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    final InputStream input = getReusableInputStream(part);

    if (part.getFileName() != null && isXmlType(part.getContentType())) {
        processXml(input);
    }
}
```

I should modify it, in order to parse the EML and get the attachments recursively, but I'm missing the big picture.

**UPDATE**: I've modified the `processAttachment` method (but it still doesn't work):

```
private void processAttachment(final Multipart multipart) {

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
            final BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);

            if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
                // part-within-a-part, do some recursion...
                extractAttachment((Multipart) bodyPart.getContent());
            }

            System.out.println("Filename: " + bodyPart.getFileName());
            System.out.println("ct: " + bodyPart.getContentType());

            final boolean isXml = bodyPart.getFileName() != null && isXmlType(bodyPart.getContentType());
            if (isXml) {
                final InputStream inputStream = getReusableInputStream(bodyPart);
                processXMLAttachment(inputStream);
            }

        }
    } [cutted]

}
```

The output is:

```
Filename: null
ct: TEXT/PLAIN; charset=iso-8859-1
Filename: null
ct: TEXT/HTML; charset=iso-8859-1
Filename: daticert.xml
ct: APPLICATION/XML; name=daticert.xml
Filename: postacert.eml
ct: MESSAGE/RFC822; name=postacert.eml
Filename: smime.p7s
ct: APPLICATION/X-PKCS7-SIGNATURE; name=smime.p7s
```

From the output, I can see that the system only scaned the first level attachments `daticert.xml` and `postacert.eml` but it didn't find the nested attachments.

More specifically, I have to read the content of:

```
Filename: postacert.eml
ct: MESSAGE/RFC822; name=postacert.eml
```

Any help, please?

Thanks

Comment: Please post an example of the mime message structure. I think you incorrectly assume that the 'EML' is an attachment, when it is just a 'normal' mimepart.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel for your reply, yes it isn't an attachment but a 'normal' `Message`, so I can send it to the begin of the process and read as a different email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I solved by checking the class of any `MimePart`, and I found that nested messages are type of `IMAPNestedMessage`, so on this kind of object I recursively call the main method `processMessage`:

```
private void processAttachment(final Multipart multipart) {

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
            final BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);

// BEGIN - Added this part
            System.out.println("CLASS bodyPart: " + bodyPart.getContent().getClass());

            if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof IMAPNestedMessage) {
                processMessage((IMAPNestedMessage) bodyPart.getContent());
            } else {
// END - Added this part
                if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
                    processAttachment((Multipart) bodyPart.getContent());
                } else {
                    final boolean isXml = bodyPart.getFileName() != null && isXmlType(bodyPart.getContentType());
                    if (isXml) {
                        final InputStream inputStream = getReusableInputStream(bodyPart);
                        processXMLAttachment(inputStream);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        sendMailService.sendMailForImportINPSFailed("metodo processAttachment()", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And now it works fine.